# Are *on hold* questions marked as deleted

Tags: support, profile-page

Viewing my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203117/user689) at SO. It says that I have 6 questions while only five appear.

My [6th question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745864/how-to-unset-a-button)
Is put on hold, but why would this make it disappear from my profile?
**Note:** *I can still access it by searching for it*

Comment: The direct answer to your question is: No, on hold (or closed) questions are not "marked" deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed this:

> [image]

The profile page summary tab is showing only top 5 voted/active/new questions, to see full list click the "view more" link or the "x Questions" title itself.

Comment: @user689 [yes it works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3BJgF.png).

Comment: It worked. I don't know what the problem was but now it is fixed.

Comment: @user689 probably browser cache.